# Problemas para obtener una tipografía en un proyecto NetBeans en Java

Tags: java, netbeans, interfaz-gráfica, font-awesome, fuentes

Dentro de mi proyecto de NetBeans tengo una **carpeta llamada `fonts`** llamada `Font_Awesome_5 _Free-Solid-900.otf` la cual quiero utilizar en un `JLabel` de nombre `lblAlertIcon_Login`

**El código es el siguiente que utilizo para llamar al archivo .otf:**

```
  try(InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/fonts/Font_Awesome_5 _Free-Solid-900.otf")){
        Font fontAwesome = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
        fontAwesome = fontAwesome.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 14);
        lblAlertIcon_Login = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        lblAlertIcon_Login.setFont(fontAwesome);
    }catch (IOException | FontFormatException exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Y lo seteo así:

```
lblAlertIcon_Login.setText("\f017");
```

El problema es que no me muestra el icono 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como nota, otras fuentes si me las toma.

Comment: ¿Has probado a escribirlo asÍ? `setText("\uF017");` (con una u delante)

Comment: Hola @ordago he probado la solución que propones utilizando el codigo de la pregunta y funciona correctamente, te recomendaría que tu comentario la pasara a una respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te falta ponerle una u delante al código del icono que estás tratando de escribir. Es decir:

```
lblAlertIcon_Login.setText("\uf017");
```

Esto es porque el léxico de los escapes unicode consiste en `\u` y el código en hexadecimal del caracter en cuestión. Si no pones la u, al poner una barra, el compilador entiende que estás tratando de generar el caracter `\f`.

`\f` es el caracter que se utiliza para indicar un salto de página en la impresión, cosa que no tiene nada que ver con lo que quieres hacer.

Más información:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.3
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html